# Best way to pass data in middleware with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I want to make user details (ex: username) appear in my nav bar, and for that I have have been sending the 'req.session.user' variable to my views.

What I've been doing is, for every view render, I send the req.session variable like so:

```
app.get('/index', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.user) {
        res.render("index", {user:req.session.user});
    }
});
```

And then in my backbone view, where my navbar is located, I print out the username.

What are the best practices to overcome this repetitive achievement?
I've searched, but had no results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to send `req.session.user` to each page like this: `{user:req.session.user}` you can add this data to [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) object:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user
    next()
})
```

Thus, on each page you can output user name like this (example with [ejs](http://ejs.co/)):

```
<% if (user) { %>
    <h1>Hello, <%= user.name %></h1>
<% } %>
```